# How to apply style to a custom control

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a custom control inheriting from `ListBox`.

I have a style for it targeting my custom control.

For some reason this style is not working on my custom control.

Could you please tell me what I am missing here?

Code for style:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxStyle" TargetType="local:CustomListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Code for custom control:

```
public class CustomListBox : ListBox
{
    public CustomListBox()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomListBox).Name;
    }

}
```

Usage of custom control:

```
<local:CustomListBox>
        <ListBoxItem Content="AAA"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="BBB"></ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem Content="CCC"></ListBoxItem>
    </local:CustomListBox>
```

Any help?

Thank you!

Comment: is this Windows 8/8.1 or WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows Phone 8.1 when you create a Templated Control (Custom control) a file is automatically created called **Generic.xaml** under **Themes** folder.
Your style should be added in Generic.xaml like this.

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomListBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter> 
</Style>
```

Change the following line to

```
this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomListBox);
```